# Table row and cell click

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

How do I create click event for table row(tr) specific and table data(td).

For example, something similar like this

```
$("table tr").on("click", function(){
      // do something with tr without td click handler
});

$("table tr td").on("click", function(){
      // do something with td without tr click handler
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide some of your code? What have you tried so far? What exactly are you expecting?

Comment: `$('table tr')` will not affect table, only all its children `tr`s . This works just like CSS.. `$('table tr td')` will just affect all children `td`s inside all children `tr`s of the `table`

Comment: why you want to do this? change your way instead of writing strange codes :)

Answer (score 2):

To bind click event to `td` element so that it doesn't fire parent `tr` click, you need to prevent event from bubbling up DOM tree. You should call [`stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) method of the event object:

```
$("table tr td").on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // do something with td without tr click handler
});
```

> do something with tr without td click handler

This is also possible if you bind click event in capturing phase (read about [event order](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)). For this you will need to use [`HTMLElement's addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) method, jQuery [`$.fn.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method bind event in bubbling stage of the event propagation. However note, that this has little practical sense if you think about it. Most likely that you want to prevent bubbling of the event in td->tr direction on some specific table cells clicks.